# MediaPlayer and ProgressBar not syncing

Tags: android, progress-bar, media-player

I have a MediaPlayer and a SeekBar to show progress. It works well enough, but the SeekBar never reaches the end. The MediaPlayer fires the onComplete event about at about 3/4 progress.

I have a runnable that is posted to a handler that updates the SeekBar location.

```
private Runnable seekBarUpdate = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        audioBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        audioPosition.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(player.getCurrentPosition() / 1000));
        handler.postDelayed(this, 25);
    }
};
```

I call `audioBar.setMax(player.getDuration())` so I can use `audioBar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition())`.

How can I sync the SeekBar with the MediaPlayer?

Comment: How big is the clip? usually small clips show such problems easily.

Comment: the test clip is a little over 1 second long.